# Return cv::Mat with Swig and use in Python

Tags: python, opencv, swig

I am returning a cv::Mat in a C++ implementation. It is wrapped with Swig and I read the return value in Python.

In Python, the type is shown as . Note, I am returning a cv::Mat, but it shows as type cv::Mat* in Python. So I can't use it as a normal opencv Image object in Python. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It also seems to me that the numpy swig wrapper doesn't accept two-dimensional arrays. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

All unspecified types are handled as pointers by SWIG. To receive a cv::Mat as a proper Python class you must provide at least that class declaration to SWIG. I have done some code with that and some others functionalities, look at https://github.com/renatoGarcia/opencv-swig

Comment: Do anyone know of a wrapper not depending on Boost?